# Using VBA to calculate cell values in rows based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem I hope I can get some help with. In a summary report I need to use date criterias: today's date compared to months in B1:M1 (all cells are date formatted using a userdefined date format to only display the monthname) to sum the rows of data only if an account number is listed in column A. (pls. see below example)

I.E. if todays date is Feb. 7th the VBA code should loop through all rows and only sum the numbers for January and february where an account # is present (it must be in VBA)

[image: Example]

Here is what I have so far:

```html
Sub Test()

Dim today, lastdayinmonth As Date
Dim i, ii As Integer
Dim months As Range

today = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
lastdayinmonth = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
months = Sheet2.Range("B2:M2")

    If idag <= lastdayinmonth Then
        For i = 3 To 20
            If Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("B" & i)) Then
            
            End If
        Next ii
            
    
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Just notice that `Dim today, lastdayinmonth As Date` only `lastdayinmonth` is being defined as `Date`. Variable `today` is being created as `Variant` because you did not specify a type. Right way should be `Dim today as Date, lastdayinmonth As Date`

Comment: Also, your code is wrong. You did `For i...next ii` clarify if its `i` or `ii`. And also, you have not defined `idag` And what I said before, it's the same for line `Dim i, ii As Integer` Actually, this code makes no real sense. And specify if the month headers are stored as values (numbers/dates) or text.

Comment: Loop thru `ColA` first to see if there is an Account number.  If you find an account number, then loop that row to sum the row, also checking row 2 for the date so you stop the loop when the date in Row 2 is > the current month.  Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your procedure and properly declare all your variables.

Comment: What range must to summarized in case of condition being True? What "sum the numbers for January and february " does mean? I am trying to prepare a code for you, but I do not understand what is to be summarized...

Comment: If only the amount found in the appropriate columns (January, February) must be added, how to return this result? Where? In Immediate Window (Debug.Print) would it be OK?

Comment: Did you find time to test the code I proposed? If yes, didn't it solve your problem as you wanted? If not, does it return an error? If yes, what error and at which line? lf not,  what wrong is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please.  It works based on the assumption that your columns header are Date formatted (no matter if they show only month...), and the sum will be returned in Imediate Window:

```
Sub TestSumMonth()
 Dim arrM As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
 Dim nSum As Long, lastRow As Long, sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = sheet2

 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 arrM = sh.Range("A1:M" & lastRow).Value
 sh.Range("O2:O" & lastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' clear the existing interior color

 For i = 1 To UBound(arrM, 1)
    If arrM(i, 1) <> Empty Then
        nSum = 0
        For j = 2 To UBound(arrM, 2)
            If Month(Date) >= Month(arrM(1, j)) Then
                nSum = nSum + arrM(i, j)
                If Month(Date) = Month(arrM(1, j)) Then
                    With sh.Range("O" & i)
                        .Value = nSum
                        .Interior.Color = vbYellow ' interior colored in yellow
                    End With
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
     End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

The code firstly clears "O:O" range interior color, then returns the sum on the appropriate row of this column and colors the cell interior in yellow...
Now, it would summarize all the passed month values plus the active month.

Comment: Welcome! But if worked as you need, ticking the check box of the left side, considering my code the answer, would not kill anybody... :)

Comment: :-) I was just testing it to be aboslutely sure before clicking the 'solved' ... Then i realized that I need to add the summed value of each row to a cell e.g. column "O" instead of the immediate window - Do you have an idea on that?

Comment: @ibcover: I updated the code to return the sum in the appropriate row of column O:O. It firstly clears the interior color of this column and then colors, the interior of the cell where it returns, in yellow. Is it OK with you?

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. And no, the idea with yellow highlights actually serves the purpose :-)

Comment: @ibcover: Then, maybe adding `.Font.Bold = True` after `.Interior.Color = vbYellow` will highlight it even better...

Comment: @ FAneDuru: I think I was a bit to early ... It appears that the calculations are not correct. I found that using todays date Feb 9th the february and march colums are added and the january is left out? when in february the JAN+FEB should be added and the rest left out and when in March JAN+GEB+MAR and so on. Any idea?

Comment: This is what you said in your question: "I.E. if todays date is Feb. 7th the VBA code should loop through all rows and only sum the numbers for January and february where an account # is present ". The code does exactly what you requested, respectively, it adds the values of the current month and of the next one. What do you want, in fact, but you couldn't clearly explain?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. The intent is to look at current date and sum all the months that have passed i.e. If in July the code should sum Jan+Feb+Mar+Apr+Jun+Jul and if in Feb it only should sum jan+feb. Right now it appears that the code sums feb+mar? Let me know if you want to have a look at the sheet and code (and wher to put it)?

Comment: @ibcover: I adapted the code to do what (I understood) you need. Please test it and let me know if it really does what you want. It will take more time to explain you what is to be done...

Comment: Think I figured it out. I've edited your code so that the routine now calculates corretly :-) Thanks again. You have been very helpful!

Comment: @ibcover: Welcome! No big problem. I've just wanted to emphasize something to not be done... I am responsible for the code I posted and only I have to adapt it, if/when the case. I like to believe that I know better what I wanted to do with the specific code... Even if I couldn't test it, not having similar data.